# Fitting an ODE model to infection data from an agent-based simulation

Tags: python, bioinformatics, curve-fitting, ode, agent-based-modeling

I am trying to fit a **S**usceptible-**I**nfectious-**R**ecovered (SIR) ODE model to infection data in python using scipy.optimize, but the infection curve of the ODE model leads to a delayed rise in infections and an overestimated peak height (see the orange line below).

The data comes from an agent-based simulation with homogeneous mixing and three states (S, I, and R). In theory, this should be in accordance with the assumptions of ODE models and the model should be able to fit perfectly. I am not sure whether my fitting method needs improvement or whether the agent-based simulation creates a shape that cannot be reproduced with a simple ODE model.

Below is the data and my attempt.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate, optimize

inf_data = [0.005,0.007,0.009,0.012,0.015,0.019,0.024,0.03,0.036,0.044,0.053,0.063,0.074,0.086,0.098,0.112,0.126,0.141,0.157,0.172,0.188,0.203,0.218,0.232,0.247,0.259,0.272,0.282,0.292,0.302,0.308,0.315,0.318,0.321,0.322,0.321,0.319,0.317,0.312,0.307,0.301,0.294,0.286,0.279,0.27,0.262,0.253,0.244,0.236,0.226,0.217,0.207,0.197,0.188,0.18,0.171,0.163,0.155,0.147,0.14,0.132,0.125,0.119,0.112,0.106,0.1,0.095,0.089,0.085,0.08,0.076,0.071,0.067,0.064,0.06,0.056,0.053,0.05,0.047,0.044,0.041,0.039,0.037,0.034,0.032,0.03,0.028,0.026,0.025,0.023,0.022,0.021,0.019,0.018,0.017,0.016,0.015,0.014,0.013,0.012,0.011] #percentage of infected
time_points = np.arange(len(inf_data))

def sir_model(y, x, beta, gamma):
    S, I, R = y
    dS = -beta * S * I / N
    dI = beta * S * I / N - gamma * I
    dR = gamma * I
    return dS, dI, dR

def fit_odeint(time_points, beta, gamma):
    return integrate.odeint(sir_model, (S0, I0, R0), time_points, args=(beta, gamma))[:,1]

# Initial values
N = 1.0
I0 = inf_data[0]
S0 = N - I0
R0 = 0.0

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(fit_odeint, time_points, inf_data)
fitted = fit_odeint(time_points, *popt)

plt.plot(time_points, inf_data, 'o')
plt.plot(time_points, fitted)
plt.show()
```

[image: blue dots: observed data; orange line: fitted model]

Comment: You say "the model should be able to fit perfectly" but then you say "or whether the agent-based simulation creates a shape that cannot be reproduced with a simple ODE model."  It sounds like you're not sure and if you're giving us data that can't fit nor *exactly* the origination of it, you can't be helped.  You don't know if this could work in the first place and left anyone who could help you without necessary and critical details.

Comment: @possum That is my assumption, but I could always be wrong. The agent-based simulation is way too much code to share here, so I decided to provide the data instead. Since my question is about model fitting, I disagree that the exact origin is a critical detail.

Comment: @possum The infection data could come from anywhere, including the real world. I was just giving additional information. As I said, I expect someone to help me with fitting the ODE model to data. If this is something you cannot help with, you are indeed wasting your time

Comment: You already have a fit then?  What is the actual problem?  You need to realize ambiguous questions are not on topic.  You really should review the rules and guidelines before you post.  Read this in great detail https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: @possum Yes, the orange line above is the fitted ODE model. The problem is that (quoting from the first sentence of the post) the infection curve of the ODE model leads to a delayed rise in infections and an overestimated peak height. I would like to improve the fit. Feel free to suggest ways to do so.

Comment: This place doesn't allow discussion for code quality, refactoring, and improvements.  Why do you think "help me optimize my fit from data of unknown origin?" would be better?

Comment: This seems to rather be a statistical problem, suggesting stats.SE or physics.SE. You are trying to find and fit a statistical model for population sizes from a stochastic simulation of a particle swarm. While the intuitive main structure may be as in the zombie apocalypse, it is quite unsurprising that it does not fit exactly, that additional smaller terms or parameters are needed for a closer fit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you have enough "play" in your model equations to fit that data. As an exercise in curve-fitting (if not in infection behaviour) you could add another parameter p in your source term for dI/dt (and sink for dS/dt), replacing I by I**p. This slightly changes the standard form of the SIR equation model, but you could regard it as equivalent to making beta and gamma weak functions of I.

Note that R is redundant in your set of equations (since S+I+R=N) - so I've removed it below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate, optimize

inf_data = [0.005,0.007,0.009,0.012,0.015,0.019,0.024,0.03,0.036,0.044,0.053,0.063,0.074,
            0.086,0.098,0.112,0.126,0.141,0.157,0.172,0.188,0.203,0.218,0.232,0.247,0.259,
            0.272,0.282,0.292,0.302,0.308,0.315,0.318,0.321,0.322,0.321,0.319,0.317,0.312,
            0.307,0.301,0.294,0.286,0.279,0.27,0.262,0.253,0.244,0.236,0.226,0.217,0.207,
            0.197,0.188,0.18,0.171,0.163,0.155,0.147,0.14,0.132,0.125,0.119,0.112,0.106,
            0.1,0.095,0.089,0.085,0.08,0.076,0.071,0.067,0.064,0.06,0.056,0.053,0.05,0.047,
            0.044,0.041,0.039,0.037,0.034,0.032]
time_points = np.arange(len(inf_data))

def sir_model(y, x, beta, gamma, p):
    S, I = y
    dS = -beta * S * I ** p / N
    dI = beta * S * I ** p / N - gamma * I ** p
    return dS, dI

def fit_odeint(time_points, beta, gamma, p ):
    return integrate.odeint(sir_model, (S0, I0), time_points, args=(beta, gamma, p))[:,1]

# Initial values
N = 1.0
I0 = inf_data[0]
S0 = N - I0

p0 = ( 0.1, 0.1, 1.0 )
bounds = ( 0.0, 2.0 )
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(fit_odeint, time_points, inf_data, p0=p0, bounds=bounds )
fitted = fit_odeint(time_points, *popt)
print( "beta, gamma, p = ", *popt)

plt.plot(time_points, inf_data, 'o')
plt.plot(time_points, fitted)
plt.show()
```

This gives

```
beta, gamma, p =  0.1599047410942999 0.05075215258403985 0.8023232790559057
```

Note that the power p is a little less than 1: you need your initial infections to rise a little faster.

[image]